# GPIO controll on electrone

Tags: javascript, electron

Been trying to use GPIO from electron with an RPI. However, as I am asking this, I was unable to do it. So I wanted to know if there was any way to archive this.

Tried using 'onoff' with electron-rebuild. However got same error as if I didn't have done the './node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild'

Comment: What's the error? Show us the code. There's not enough here for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get:
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
exportGpio
node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:16